# Has python package serial been renamed to pyserial?

Tags: python, pyserial

A quick question, as I was learning to set up a serial connection via python. I googled for according packages and found mainly two across the internet: `serial` and `pyserial`.

However, it seems there is only documentation to be found for `pyserial`, although both have a lot of stackoverflow entries.

Could it be that the `serial` package has been renamed to `pyserial`?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Look at the example code or reference. It will probably answer your question.

Comment: Shame on me, I only looked for the documentation belonging to the package name serial. Didn't know there could be one and the same package going under different names. Why the ambiguity though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`serial`](https://pypi.org/project/serial/#description) package on Pypi is something different to [`pyserial`](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/#description).

Maybe what's confusing you is that you need to install Pyserial with `pip install pyserial`, but import it with `serial`. The name a package can be imported by gets set in the [packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#packages) field in their `setup.py`. [Here's](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/setup.py#L60) the one for Pyserial. It can be different to the name of the package on Pypi.

Comment: so serial is just a module of the pyserial package?

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand it.